# Array Median If statement not working

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, median

I have a Median If Array formula that brings back one of the results from the list rather than calculating the median of the values. Below is the formula. I think the issue may be caused by the formula referring to entire columns and not including an if statement related to <>"", but have not been successful figuring out where that would go. Any thoughts are much appreciated!

{=IFERROR(MEDIAN(IF(Raw!$L:$L=$A3,IF(Raw!$B:$B=$D$1,IF($B3="mg/L",Raw!$M:$M,Raw!$N:$N)))),"No Data")}

I want the formula to do the following: "If the common name in A3 matches a value in Raw L, and if the sample station in D1 matches a value in Raw B, and if the units in B3 are "mg/L", then calculate the median of the results in Raw M. Otherwise if the units are not "mg/L, then calculate the median from the results in Column N. If there are no results at all, then state "No Data" in the cell.

Comment: not sure what you mean, the formula is designed to only return one number, the Median.  Is it returning the wrong number?

Comment: It returns one of the results from the list, rather than calculating the median from the list. For example, if the results are 2, 3, 4, and 5, it reports a 5 instead of the calculated median of 3.5.

Comment: Try working on a smaller section of data and evaluate the formula by highlighting a portion of the formula in the formula bar and tapping F9.  Can you confirm your If statements are returning the values you expect and that they aren't just returning 5?

Comment: I do not get that, unless I forget to hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Ack. I apologize- my QAQC check was calculating the average (not the median), and it just so happens that the median values for the parameters I checked were the same as actual values. The formulas actually are working. Sorry to waste your time. Is it possible to delete my post?